# how to find Vout for this fourier transform , given Vin

Tags: filter

[image]

I don't know how to deal with the summation form !!!
It's an old exercise from my friends notebook .

Answer (score 1):

Well, notice that the summation is given by:

$$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\sum_{\text{n}=-7}^7\frac{2\exp\left(200\text{n}t\text{j}\right)}{1-\text{n}\text{j}}=\frac{2\exp\left(200\left(-7\right)t\text{j}\right)}{1-\left(-7\right)\text{j}}+\dots+\frac{2\exp\left(200\cdot7t\text{j}\right)}{1-7\text{j}}\tag1$$

And you know that:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right):=\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{out}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)}{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)}=\frac{10^{-6}\omega\text{j}}{\left(1+10^{-6}\omega\text{j}\right)^2}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{out}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{10^{-6}\omega\text{j}}{\left(1+10^{-6}\omega\text{j}\right)^2}\cdot\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\tag2$$